# How to align elements in html and css?

Tags: html, css

I want to write a little html page that contains a little search function. I want to write a page like that :

[image]
I created the buttons but I don't know how to align them and decorate them to look like the image above. I don't want to use bootstratp but ton only do this using css. But I don't know css well...

The idea that I got is to use a  tag, so here is my html code :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Invoice Number :</td>
      <td>
        <input name="invoiceNumber">
      </td>

      <td>Invoice Supplier Name :</td>
      <td>
        <input name="invoiceSupplier">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Invoice Status :</td>
      <td>
        <select name="invoiceStatus">

          <option> </option>
          <option> Import error </option>
          <option> Invoice control required </option>
          <option> Other Document </option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td>Invoice Category :</td>
      <td>

        <select name="invoiceCategory">
          <option></option>
          <option>Invoice with PO and GR</option>
          <option>Invoice with GR</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Order :</td>
      <td>
        <select name="order">

          <option> Number </option>
          <option> Supplier </option>
          <option> Date </option>
          <option> Net Amount </option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <button type="button">Search</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="detail">
          <button type="reset">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

But I'm not really sure that is a good idea. Can you please help to fix that :

- How can I align the button like in the image? (buttons at the same lign, search and cancel button at the right side).
- How can I decorate the buttons to look like the image? I mean how can I use css to have blue buttons rather than the default buttons??

Thank you !

Comment: Perhaps look at expanding your knowledge base, rather than looking for an immediate solution. Here is an [Introduction to Modern CSS Buttons](https://www.sitepoint.com/modern-css-buttons/)

Comment: One thing to note here is that you can style the `input` & `button` elements using css, however you cannot style the `select` & `option` elements (which means you have to create your own to represent the `select` behaviour you want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can align using the below html code but the best way is to use div based structure

```css
 button{ background:#33b5e5; border:none; padding:12px 35px;color:#fff;margin-right:60px; display:inline-block; margin-top:10px;
     }
     select,input{ padding:6px; min-height:20px; vertical-align:middle; }
     .mr-30{margin-right:30px;}
     td{line-height:40px;}
```

```html
     <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Invoice Number :</td>
          <td>
            <input name="invoiceNumber" class="mr-30">
          </td>
    
          <td>Invoice Supplier Name :</td>
          <td>
            <input name="invoiceSupplier">
          </td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
          <td>Invoice Status :</td>
          <td>
            <select name="invoiceStatus" class="mr-30">
    
              <option> </option>
              <option> Import error </option>
              <option> Invoice control required </option>
              <option> Other Document </option>
            </select>
          </td>
    
          <td>Invoice Category :</td>
          <td>
    
            <select name="invoiceCategory">
              <option></option>
              <option>Invoice with PO and GR</option>
              <option>Invoice with GR</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
        
          <td colspan="4" style="text-align:right">
            <div class="detail">
            <button type="button">Search</button>
              <button type="reset">Cancel</button>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue here is that you are using Tables for structuring your layout.

> **[This is the most obsolete way of doing things there is.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/Table_Layout_Strategy)**

What You can do now, is to learn the latest CSS methods of creating your layout, focusing on **[CSS grids.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids)**

Then, you can get your hands on a CSS pre-processor like SASS and then learn a proper framework for it like **[Bourbon.](http://bourbon.io/)**

The latest and greatest way of aligning things the way you want to, is using the **[Flexbox model.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

In the latest version of CSS, there is even a **[grid format property](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)** setting which will make things even easier.

Answer (score 0):

I also think it would makes sense to expand your knowledge base.
It is very old fashioned to use a table to format your layout.
For example you can put the two buttons outside the table and give them a 'margin-left' with css.

For the button decoration you are looking for the css attributes color(white), background-color(blue), padding, width and height.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use  instead of  because table structure will give problem in responsive design.
2. Use CSS property "display: inline-block" where you want to align fields in to same line.
3. Use CSS property background-color, color, etc to decorate your buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Kahn Academy does a good (and free!) course on the basics of HTML and CSS. They also go on to teach about interactivity on web pages using javascript which will be essential to know if you want your buttons to do anything once you've made them look good.

https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/html-css

Answer (score 0):

Try with working demo , run the snippet and change it to full screen

```css
* {
   box-sizing:border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
   -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border-spacing: 0;
}
input, select {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 10px 15px;
}
table td {
 padding: 15px;
}
button {
 background: #33b5e5;
 border: none;
 padding: 12px 35px;
 color: #fff;
 margin-right:14px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Invoice Number :</td>
    <td><input name="invoiceNumber"></td>
    <td>Invoice Supplier Name :</td>
    <td><input name="invoiceSupplier"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Invoice Status :</td>
    <td><select name="invoiceStatus">
        <option> </option>
        <option> Import error </option>
        <option> Invoice control required </option>
        <option> Other Document </option>
      </select></td>
    <td>Invoice Category :</td>
    <td><select name="invoiceCategory">
        <option></option>
        <option>Invoice with PO and GR</option>
        <option>Invoice with GR</option>
      </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Order :</td>
    <td><select name="order">
        <option> Number </option>
        <option> Supplier </option>
        <option> Date </option>
        <option> Net Amount </option>
      </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td><button type="button">Search</button> <button type="reset">Cancel</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```